# What is the influence of long excitation pulses on the relationship between luminescence intensity and the excitation intensity (Bimolecular process)?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In the luminescence processes (Bimolecular process), if long excitation pulses were used, and after a transient initial increase in luminescence intensity, *i(t)*, the steady-state value of intensity is still looks like
$$i(0)=\left(\frac{\beta_{\text{r}}}{\beta_{\text{r}}+\beta_{\text{nr}}}\right)G
 = \left(\frac{\beta_{\text{r}}}{\beta_{\text{r}}+\beta_{\text{nr}}}\right)\alpha I_{\text{ex}} $$

(same like the short excitation pulses). Why?